# Multiple wishlist for magento2

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I am looking for multiple wishlists programmatically in magento2.1, till yet I tried like when customer click on wishlist I gave popup so there he can select already created wishlist if not have to create wishlist working fine but then I am sending that to wishlist id to override magento2's default but it's not 
so please do the needful.

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for your case ? Have you found a community package ? I'm searching for one to avoir creating this feature

Comment: if you're looking paid module of [magento 2 multiple wishlists](https://www.mageants.com/multiple-wishlists-extension-for-magento-2.html) then you can go and test manually as per your request